# In PostgreSQL, how to get number of event per day between a period including days without events (0 values)

Tags: postgresql, date, count, gaps-and-islands, generate-series

I need to find the way to get the number of events that happens in every day between a period, including days in which no event occurs, getting that day a 0 value.

I try this query:

```
SELECT f.day, COALESCE(count(e.*), 0) account
FROM (SELECT d::date day
        FROM generate_series('2023-01-19'::date - '39 day'::interval, '2023-01-19', '1 day'::interval) d) f 
LEFT JOIN events e ON f.day::date = e.event_date::date
WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN ('2023-01-19'::date - interval '39 days') AND '2023-01-19'
GROUP BY f.day
ORDER BY f.day desc
```

But, i am not getting 0 values. The period is for 40 days, but only get 31 records (9 days with no events at all doesn't appears).

I see this, [Postgres, Count entries per day including days with none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379043/postgres-count-entries-per-day-including-days-with-none)

but somehow seems to be like my query. But my query is not working...

Thanks for any idea!

**Edit: solution**
The only way that i am getting what i want is getting rid of the WHERE clause.
My real query has some more filters aplied.

```
WHERE e.state = 2 AND e.other_field IS NOT NULL
```

Following both great answer from Adrian or Edouard, i get the same result (but 1. they do not have all de information needed, WHERE was not complete in the problem presented, and 2. they really give me a path to find the answer).
The thing that works, is move that filter to the join (avoiding re filtering by date).

```
LEFT JOIN events e ON f.day::date = e.event_date::date AND e.state = 2 AND e.other_field IS NOT NULL
```

Then i get what i want.

Comment: 1) `count` will not return `NULL`, so the `coalesce` is not needed. 2) Eliminate the `WHERE` clause, that is already taken care of by `ON f.day::date = e.event_date::date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue comes from your WHERE clause to be replaced by :

```
 WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN ('2023-01-19'::date - interval '39 days') AND '2023-01-19' :: date
    OR e.event_date IS NULL
```

or simply to be cancelled as stated by @Adrian because it is redundant with the LEFT JOIN with the `generate_series` in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT f.date, count(e.*)
  FROM generate_series('2023-01-19'::date - '39 day'::interval, '2023-01-19', '1 day'::interval) AS f(date)
  LEFT JOIN events AS e
    ON e.event_date = f.date :: date
  GROUP BY f.date
 ORDER BY f.date DESC
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7mbQO69m)

Comment: Not really the answer. You don't need a `FILTER`, because 1) `select count(null); 0`. 2) @Speaker wants the `NULL` values counted so they return  `0` for days that don't exist in the  `events` table.

Comment: @Adrian : "Not really the answer" ? My suggestion returns 0 for the days that don't exist in the events table. Then `count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.event_date IS NOT NULL)` can be replaced by `count(e.event_date)` or `count(e.*)`. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to you both! @AdrianKlaver and @Edouard!!

Comment: @Edouard, I could have sworn that the `FILTER` did not work in my test case. I just ran it again and realized I was wrong. The best I can say is that it is extra code that can be simplified down to what you ended up with.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver extra code that can simplify the solution will be welcome! ;)

Comment: @Speaker, is the solution above not working for you?  As Edouard has made it as simple as it can get and it should work.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it works. I edit the question providing a complete solution to my problem as there be more data that affect it. There i thank you both!